Examples of curves $C$ with $\operatorname{Jac}(C) \cong E^3$, $E$ a CM elliptic curve
Let $k$ be a field of your choice— I'm particularly interested in algebraically closed fields. Are there explicit examples of curves over $k$ whose Jacobian is isogenous to the product of three copies of a CM elliptic curve $E$ over $k$? Yuri Zarhin's answer to When is a product of elliptic curves isogenous to the Jacobian of a hyperelliptic curve? says that when $k = \mathbb{C}$, such a curve exists for any $E$ (no CM assumption necessary).

There are a number of examples in this paper, §4.
